# "version `GOMP_4.0' not found" when xgboost imported in python - Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, xgboost, ensemble-learning

HiI have installed the xgboost using the the following link for the Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Platform

http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html

when I run the following command in the python terminal it throws as exception as shown the following screenshot

import xgboost as xg

[image]

any kind of help would be greatly appreciated

I also have tried the following commands but no luck

===================================================================

sudo apt-get install make

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcc

sudo apt-get install g++

sudo apt-get install git

sudo git clone https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost

cd xgboost

sudo ./build.sh

cd python-package

sudo /home/username/anaconda2/bin/python setup.py install

===================================================================

Thanks for ur time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kind of late answer, but for future people coming here. I have faced the very same problem, but for XGBoost on Java. It turns out `libgomp` is required. On Debian it just took an `apt-get install -y libgomp1` and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

This [link](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1786) helped me out with the Gomp issue, as I finally got xboost to load and was able to do "Fitting XGBoost to the Training  set":

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
classifier = XGBClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Unfortunately the `classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)` crashed the script saying that the "kernel had to be reloaded"

Working on that right now

Comment: I might also add I added XGBoost to one of my R projects (install.packages("xgboost") and it worked flawlessly on the same Linuxmint 18 32 bit box